# HBase unit tests throw InstanceAlreadyExistsException with HBaseTestingUtility

Tags: junit, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have a package that makes use of HBase's `HBaseTestingUtility` for creating and running a mini HBase cluster. Everything appears to work fine, but in the output I get a number of exceptions that I would like to deal with. This is the first such exception:

```
12/04/03 21:17:58 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 36681: starting
12/04/03 21:17:58 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 36681: starting
12/04/03 21:17:58 WARN impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Metrics system not started: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-datanode.properties, hadoop-metrics2.properties
12/04/03 21:17:58 WARN util.MBeans: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=MetricsSystem,sub=Control
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Hadoop:service=DataNode,name=MetricsSystem,sub=Control
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:467)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1520)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:986)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:938)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:330)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.util.MBeans.register(MBeans.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.initSystemMBean(MetricsSystemImpl.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.init(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.initialize(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.startDataNodes(MiniDFSCluster.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:311)
    at edu.ucsc.srl.persia.PersiaAdminTest.setUpBeforeClass(PersiaAdminTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

This is what the basic unit test looks like

```
public class MyTest {
    private final static HBaseTestingUtility TEST_UTIL = new HBaseTestingUtility();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
      TEST_UTIL.startMiniCluster(3);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
      TEST_UTIL.shutdownMiniCluster();
    }
...
}
```

And just in case it matters, here in my pom.xml with the relevant versions of everything:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.ucsc.srl</groupId>
  <artifactId>persia</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>Persia</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>0.90.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.20.205.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>0.90.5</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-test</artifactId>
      <version>0.20.205.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

These exceptions seem to be popping up everywhere with HBaseTestingUtility and associated MR type tests. An example is here [0] From my browsing of HBase Jira issues it seems that they've been logged but currently not addressed/resolved...

[0] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-5711